# dataframe column returned in a new dataframe with changed values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
def get_list_of_university_towns():
   states = {'CA' : 'California', 'SC' : 'South Carolina'}
   df = pd.read_csv(filename) # filename.csv has many columns 'State' and 'RegionName' are within
   df_res = df[['State', 'RegionName']]
   return df_res
```

The function returns a nice list of the piece of the information I am looking for. How can I return the 'State' column but replaced:

```
df_res.loc[:, 'State'].replace(states)
```

I had tried `return [df_res.loc[:, 'State'].replace(states), df['RegionName']]` but it returns 2 Dataframes.
I know replacement could be done in original **df** but can I leave df as is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First solution [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) column separately:

```
def get_list_of_university_towns():
   states = {'CA' : 'California', 'SC' : 'South Carolina'}
   df = pd.read_csv(filename)
   df_res = df[['State', 'RegionName']]
   df_res['State'] = df_res['State'].replace(states)
   return df_res
```

Another solution is to define `replace` column in `dict`:

```
def get_list_of_university_towns():
   states = {'CA' : 'California', 'SC' : 'South Carolina'}
   df = pd.read_csv(filename)
   df_res = df[['State', 'RegionName']].replace({'State':states})
   return df_res
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'State':['SC','CA'], 'RegionName':['CA','SC'], 'col':[5,8]})
states = {'CA' : 'California', 'SC' : 'South Carolina'}
df_res = df[['State', 'RegionName']].replace({'State':states})
print (df_res)
            State RegionName
0  South Carolina         CA
1      California         SC

print (df)
  RegionName State  col
0         CA    SC    5
1         SC    CA    8
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the key here is to copy the original df, then modify the column using either reassignment or the `inplace` argument. Below is the df definition I used to test my example.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'State': ['CA', 'SC', 'CA', 'SC', 'CA', 'SC', 'CA', 'SC'],
                   'RegionName': ['SW', 'NE', 'SW', 'NE', 'SW', 'NE', 'SW', 'NE'],
                   'College': ['College1', 'College2', 'College1', 'College2', 'College1', 'College2', 'College1', 'College2']})
```

Result:

```
    College RegionName State
0  College1         SW    CA
1  College2         NE    SC
2  College1         SW    CA
3  College2         NE    SC
4  College1         SW    CA
5  College2         NE    SC
6  College1         SW    CA
7  College2         NE    SC
```

From there I used copied the df and used your dictionary, `states = {'CA': 'California', 'SC': 'South Carolina'}`, to replace the column in the new df.

```
df_res = df.loc[:, ['State', 'RegionName']]
df_res.State.replace(states, inplace=True)
```

but could look like:

```
df_res = df.loc[:, ['State', 'RegionName']]
df_res['State'] = df_res.State.replace(states)
```

Which resulted in:

## **df=**

```
    College RegionName State
0  College1         SW    CA
1  College2         NE    SC
2  College1         SW    CA
3  College2         NE    SC
4  College1         SW    CA
5  College2         NE    SC
6  College1         SW    CA
7  College2         NE    SC
```

## **df_res=**

```
            State RegionName
0      California         SW
1  South Carolina         NE
2      California         SW
3  South Carolina         NE
4      California         SW
5  South Carolina         NE
6      California         SW
7  South Carolina         NE
```